# How do I open one URL at a time from text file with Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, tkinter

I'm trying to open one URL at a time (in order as it is in the text file) when I click on the Test button. What my code does is open all URLs weirdly one after another repeatedly.

Text file:

```
https://google.com
https://yahoo.com
https://facebook.com
https://youtube.com
```

Here's the code:

```
import tkinter as tk

from random import *

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from time import *

root = tk.Tk()

app_width = 1000
app_height = 620

screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()

x = (screen_width / 2) - (app_width / 2)
y = (screen_height / 2) - (app_height / 2)

root.geometry(f'{app_width}x{app_height}+{int(x)}+{int(y)}')

PATH ="C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"

testbtn_txt = tk.StringVar()
testbtn = tk.Button(root, textvariable=testbtn_txt, command=lambda:testfunc(), font="Arial", bg="#808080", fg="white", height=1, width=10)
testbtn_txt.set("Test")
testbtn.grid(row=10, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=5, padx=5)

def testfunc():
    global driver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

    sleep(5)
    f = open("updatedlist.txt")
    urls = [url.strip() for url in f.readlines()]
    for url in urls:
        driver.get(url)

    return driver

root.mainloop()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am new. Been trying to understand. I searched this code and tried to make it work but failed. You're right about "for". I didn't know that. What should I do instead?

Comment: what do you want to do? do you want each of the button clicks to open the next url?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I want to do.

Comment: do you necessarily need to use `selenium`?

Comment: Yup. My entire program uses it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you read the URLs into a list and convert that list to an iterator. That allows to simply use `next` to get the next URL. So pressing the button will simply open the `next` URL and if there are no more to open it will stop the function from further execution:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from selenium import webdriver


PATH ="C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

with open('myfile.txt') as file:
    urls = iter([line.strip() for line in file])


def open_next():
    try:
        driver.get(next(urls))
    except StopIteration:
        print('no more urls')
        return


root = tk.Tk()

btn = tk.Button(root, text='Open next url', command=open_next)
btn.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

A couple of other things:
You don't need to use `.readlines` and it is better to use `with` (context manager) to open files. There is no need to use `lambda` in `command` if the function takes no arguments. Also don't use `time`, it has no place in this architecture since it freezes the entire thread and process and you rarely if ever want that to happen to a GUI. Also `Variable`s such as `StringVar`s are not really needed for `Button`s, just use their `text` argument and if you need that to change use `config`.

Also:
I strongly advise against using wildcard (`*`) when importing something, You should either import what You need, e.g. `from module import Class1, func_1, var_2` and so on or import the whole module: `import module` then You can also use an alias: `import module as md` or sth like that, the point is that don't import everything unless You actually know what You are doing; name clashes are the issue.

Comment: What should I use in this architecture instead of time?

Comment: @Cassano depends on what you want to do, but if you want to delay some function, you can use `after` method, which basically will schedule the given function to run roughly after the time given, also `time` can be used in other threads if needed, it is more that in the same thread and process as `tkinter` it shouldn't be used because it makes `tkinter` freeze which is not really great for the user (the same happens with long running functions too, it all simply blocks the `mainloop` from updating stuff)

Comment: After 5 seconds, for example... I want to print("hello world)

Comment: @Cassano well you use some widget for example `root` and you do `root.after(5000, print, 'hello world')`, the first argument is milliseconds, the second is the function, and the rest are arguments to pass to that function (except for keyword arguments, if you need to pass those, the easiest is to use `lambda` I guess, but you can search that up if needed)

Comment: This freezes the GUI too. I tried: 

root.after(5000)
print("Hello world")

Comment: @Cassano that is not how to use it, I have pretty clearly shown how it should be used for scheduling in my comment, you really had to just copy-paste from there

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is caused by the fact you are opening the urls directly and immediately in the `for` loop

```py
f = open("updatedlist.txt")
urls = [url.strip() for url in f.readlines()]
for url in urls:
    driver.get(url)
```

I'm not familiar with `tkinter` so I can't say how exactly your code should be, but the logic should be as following:

```py
f = open("updatedlist.txt")
urls = [url.strip() for url in f.readlines()]
for url in urls:
    #here create a button based on the current url and click it
```

Comment: I'm confused... I just want one URL to open upon click of the button. Each time the button is pressed, it will open the next link in order.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what do you mean by `Each time the button is pressed, it will open the next link in order` ?

Comment: For example: I press the Test button, the first URL in the text file will be opened. Sorry, my bad, forget what I said about every next link. I figured that's a bad idea.

Comment: Now I'm totally not understanding what's going on here.... Can you explain what exactly is your problem? Did my answer helped?

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't, but thanks though.